# URL rewriting doesn't work right after adding a query string line into it

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This URL rewriting lines work fine **till the query string line**, and after the query string any of them not work.

```
ReWriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^home?$ /mysite/index.php
ReWriteRule ^gallery?$ /mysite/gallery.php
ReWriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)?$ /mysite/owner.php?name=$1
ReWriteRule ^about?$ /mysite/about.php
ReWriteRule ^location?$ /mysite/location.php
```

The first two lines *home* and *gallery* works as expected (including the third line *query string*), but the other two lines *about and location* don't work.
If I requested those two pages **with the rewritten name**, **the pages not comes to browser** (the response is nothing, besides I am getting the same page with i am currently on - not even getting a 404 error message), but if I requested those pages **with the original name with the .php extension** the page comes to the browser. I tried putting those two *about and location* **at the top of the query string line, then those two pages work fine as expected**, but when they are below of the query string line then only they don't work.
Can I know what is wrong with the URL Rewriting methoed? I still can't able to figure the problem out.

Comment: You should add the last flag in `[L]`  This ends the rewriting once a match has happened, otherwise you can get multiple match/modification and this could cause unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your attempt, here is a slightly modified version:

```
ReWriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^/?home/?$ /mysite/index.php [END]
ReWriteRule ^/?gallery/?$ /mysite/gallery.php [END]
ReWriteRule ^/?about/?$ /mysite/about.php [END]
ReWriteRule ^/?location/?$ /mysite/location.php [END]
ReWriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /mysite/owner.php?name=$1 [END]
```

The order of rules is important. The more general ones should be placed *below* the more specialized ones.

In case you experience a http status 500 (server internal error) with above setup chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case replace the `[END]` flag with the `[L]` flag which should also work fine in this scenario.

---

Above rules will work likewise in the real http servers host configuration and in dynamic configuration file.

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Why do I have to use the [END] flag in each ReWriteRule? I have seen many URL ReWriteRule tutotials on the web, yet  I haven't come across putting [END] flag

Comment: @SaraRobert You do not always have to! It might be that you have additional rewriting rules apart from the ones you posted here. In such scenarios unexpected interference between different rules may occur. It often is safer to add such a flag to prevent a once rewritten request to get rewritten _again_. Certainly, if above rules are and will stay the only ones, then you can omit the flag.

Comment: When did they start using `[END]` guess I am showing my age, I don't do much with rewrite anymore as i use a more preferred method of URI routing.  `index.php/about/somepage` where I just remove `index.php`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix The http server in version 2.4 introduced the `[END]` flag. The difference to the older `[L]` flag is documented, of course. Rule of thumb: `END` is the new `L`.

Comment: @arkascha - thanks, I don't use .htaccess anymore, in fact I try to avoid it for compatibility with IIS

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Actually that has little to do with dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"), but with the rewriting engine implemented by the apache http server. Other servers have different engines, thus different syntax.

Comment: @arkascha these two methods stilll don't work. First I tried with putting [L], and then with [END].

Comment: @SaraRobert And "don't work" means what _exactly_? Did you copy my rule set or just applied the `[END]` flag?

Comment: @arkascha Can I know what is the purpose of putting **?/** at the beginning each Rule?

Comment: @SaraRobert It makes the rule work likewise in the real host configuration and in dynamic configuration files. The request starts with a leading `/`, but that is stripped when applying a rule in a dynamic configuration file, since those are applied from a _relative_ position in the document file hierarchy. One of the many reasons why rules should preferably be placed in the real host configuration.

Comment: @arkascha Do you mind explaining me that in a better way please?

Comment: @SaraRobert Sorry, but what detail do you need additional information about?

Comment: Why do I have to put **/?** at the start and **/** at the end on every rule? is it optional or must? and I don;t understand what is that real host configuration and dynamic host configuration. please explain me :)

Comment: @arkascha and one more question.
"I have noticed you mentioned in your answer this:
The order of rules is important. The more general ones should be placed below the more specialized ones."

Why do I have to put it even If I already put [L] flag in every single ReWriteRule?

Comment: @SaraRobert I answered to the leading `/?` sequence, I suggests you start reading into the documentation of the tools you use, here the rewriting module of the apache http server. As typical for OpenSource projects that documentation is of excellent quality and comes with really helpful examples. The trailing `/?` allows to capture requests with or without trailing slash likewise, that usually does make sense. Dynamic configuration files are what are usually referred to as `.htaccess` files (though they can be named whatever you prefer). I already referred to that in the question itself.

Comment: @SaraRobert About the order of rules: if you have more general rules further up, then the lower ones won't get processed any more, since the more general rule already applied. Think of it like this: first test for the specific exception, then have a more general "catch all rule" to follow.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for taking your time to answer for this question and to my comments as well.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

Answer (score 1):

I would change the order of these

```
ReWriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)?$ /mysite/owner.php?name=$1
ReWriteRule ^about?$ /mysite/about.php
ReWriteRule ^location?$ /mysite/location.php
```

To

```
ReWriteRule ^about$ /mysite/about.php [L]
ReWriteRule ^location$ /mysite/location.php [L]
ReWriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /mysite/owner.php?name=$1 [L]
```

And add the last flag.

what happens is that the `^([a-z0-9]+)?` is more generic and matches and changes the URL before the last 2 rules are reached.

In other words, if you had a URL with `about` it matches this `^([a-z0-9]+)?` gets changed and then does not match the actual rule for it.  So by putting the more generic rule last you can avoid this.

Also as I said in the comments, I would add the `[L]` flag in or `Last` so that it ends the rewriting once a match is done, otherwise you can get unexpected matches.

You can also combine some of these (probably)

```
 ReWriteRule ^(about|location)$ /mysite/$1.php [L]
```

I am pretty sure that the `?` means the preceding match is optional, but I removed it because if not then the capture group is optional.  So I am not sure what the purpose you had of having it there.  Because as I read it this means `^about?$` with the `t` being optional...

Comment: m pretty sure that the ? means the preceding match is optional, but I removed it because if not then the capture group is optional. So I am not sure what the purpose you had of having it there. Because as I read it this means ^about?$ with the t being optional...

Can you explain me this? as  I don't get what you saying by this

Comment: Anyways thanks for talking your time to answer for this question

Comment: Sorry I was busy reworking my Debug library so I can put it on `packagist` AKA composer.